# Interrupts in AT89S52 using C code

Tags: c, embedded, isr

Can I call function outside of ISR,from inside of an ISR which is call by other function(eg. from MAIN) in AT89S52 using C?

Comment: Could you please explain with some pseudo code ?

Answer (score 1):

Calling a function from an ISR in any architecture is legal - though not always advisable.

You need to consider whether the function in question is suitable for execution within interrupts and multiple thread contexts; for example it will need to be reentrant and must access shared resources atomically or in a manner that ensures consistency, and should not of course block or busy-wait indeterminately.

You may also need to consider stack requirement for calling the function and the function call overhead itself in terms of interrupt processing time.  In-lining teh function might be considered.

Comment: Beware that the 8051 doesn't much like reentrant/recursive functions though, due to the architecture's restrictive stack and pointer arithmetic C compilers typically prefer statically allocated overlays in place of true stack storage for local variables. Therefore the callee tree may need to be specially marked to use a reentrant calling convention, depending on the particular compiler and its settings.

Comment: @doynax : All good points - I did mention the need to consider stack requirement, and suggested that it is not always advisable - even when possible.  This is especially true on such constrained environments, and you have elaborated on some of architecture specific considerations. Thanks.